# Instance of inner class as default value for outer class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'd like to use an instance of an inner class (in this case a `namedtuple` although the exact same symptoms occur for an inner class defined with `class`) as a default value for an outer class method (in this case the constructor). However, when this code is imported from a different module the outer class definition seems to be missing.

Example:

```
# mymodule.py

from typing import NamedTuple, Tuple

class IdSignal():
    Cfg = NamedTuple('IdSignalCfg', [
        ('nfft', int),
        ('limits', Tuple[float, float]),
        ('min_spacing', float),
        ('nmix', int)])
    Cfg.__new__.__defaults__ = (
        512,
        (1500, 7500),
        200,
        3
    )

    def __init__(self, cfg = IdSignal.Cfg()):
        self.cfg = cfg
```

Now executing `import mymodule` throws:

```
Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'IdSignal' is not defined
  File "...", line 18, in IdSignal
    def __init__(self, cfg = IdSignal.Cfg()):
  File "...", line 5, in <module>
    class IdSignal():
  ...
    import mymodule
```

Confusingly, both pylint and mypy don't recognize any error in the above code.

Can this be achieved any other way?

I understand I can use `None` as a default value and instantiate `IdSignal.Cfg` **within** the constructor. If this is the only solution, I'd like to understand **why** is the above code failing?

Comment: Could you also post the code for the outer class?
Edit - My bad Cfg is the inner class, thanks for clarifying for me chepner

Comment: `IdSignal` is the outer class; the inner class is the namedtuple type `Cfg`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the time `__init__` is defined, the name `IdSignal` isn't yet bound to the class. (That doesn't happen until the *entire* body of the `class` statement is evaluated, and the result of that evaluation is passed to the relevant metaclass.) However, `Cfg` is also not yet a class attribute; it's just a name in the same "scope" in which `__init__` is defined, so you don't need to qualify the name.

```
def __init__(self, cfg=Cfg()):
    self.cfg = cfg
```

---

A `class` statement like

```
class Foo:
    x = 3
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
# These names don't really matter, but I'm using different
# names than what the attributes will be just to emphasize
# the point that they really are distinct objects before
# the new class is ever created.

class_x = 3

def some_init(self, y):
    self.y = y

Foo = type('Foo', (object,), {'__init__': some_init, 'x': class_x})
```

Notice that the name `Foo` doesn't come into existence until the very end. A `class` statement doesn't define a new scope like a module or function does, but neither are names defined in a `class` statement part of any enclosing scope; think of them as temporary names that are discarded once the class is created.